# Simple PHP IF Statement Does Not Evaluate Correctly

Tags: php

This PHP IF statement always results in 'false' and I can't figure out why. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Where $i is passed in as 0 and $j is passed in as 4 (these numbers were verified in the POST)

```
$i = $_POST['entry'];
$j = $_POST['j'];

function tabs() {
  if ($i < $j)
    echo 'i is less than j';
  else
    echo 'false';
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$i` and `$j` are not within the [visible scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of `tabs()`:

> … [W]ithin user-defined functions a local function scope is introduced. Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope.

Pass them as parameters or make them global (the first being the preferred way):

**Parameters**

```
$i = $_POST['entry'];
$j = $_POST['j'];

function tabs($i, $j) {
  if ($i < $j)
    echo 'i is less than j';
  else
    echo 'false';
};

tabs($i, $j);
```

**Global**

```
$i = $_POST['entry'];
$j = $_POST['j'];

function tabs() {
  global $i, $j;
  if ($i < $j)
    echo 'i is less than j';
  else
    echo 'false';
};

tabs();
```

---

**EDIT**
Alternatively, you can access the superglobal `$_POST` array from within the `tabs()` function directly, or `$_GLOBALS['i']` and `$_GLOBALS['j']`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, this got it. I used the first method and that took care of the problem.